# How to do a group by while iterating over a data frame?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

How do I modify my code such that it does the comparison within the ID column, I don't want to compare the first row of ID 70 and the last row of 68.

```
for i in range(1,len(df)):
    if pd.isnull(df.loc[i,'Col 2']) and pd.isnull(df.loc[i,'Col 1']) and df.loc[i-1,'Col 2']=='In Progress':
        df.loc[i,'Col 2']=df.loc[i-1,'Col 2']
        df.loc[i,'Col 1']=df.loc[i-1,'Col 1']
```

Current View:

```
ID  Col 1   Col 2
68      
68  TSW     In Progress
68  TSW     In Progress
68  TPD     In Progress
68      
68  RT      Completed
68      
68      
70      
70  SISN    In Progress
70  SISN    In Progress
70  SNIS    In Progress
70      
70  TT       In Progress
70      
70
```

Expected:

```
ID  Col 1   Col 2
68      
68  TSW     In Progress
68  TSW     In Progress
68  TPD     In Progress
68  TPD     In Progress 
68  RT      Completed
68              
68              
70  
70  SISN    In Progress
70  SISN    In Progress
70  SNIS    In Progress
70  SNIS    In Progress
70  TT      In Progress
70  TT      In Progress
70  TT      In Progress
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly you'd like to apply the snipped of the code only to rows that correspond to the same "ID". In that case you need to group by your dataframe by "ID" column at some point. One of the possible solutions could be the following:

```
df_grouped = df.groupby("ID")
for groupName, groupDf in df_grouped:
    for i in range(1,len(groupDf): # Loop through each group
        if pd.isnull(groupDf.iloc[i]['Col 2']) and pd.isnull(groupDf.iloc[i]['Col 1']) and groupDf.iloc[i-1]['Col 2']=='In Progress': # switch to iloc in order to retrieve i-th element in the groupDf
            i2 = groupDf.iloc[i].name  # Get original index
            df.loc[i2,'Col 2']=df2.loc[i2-1,'Col 2']
            df.loc[i2,'Col 1']=df2.loc[i2-1,'Col 1']
```

Hopefully this sets you on the right track